# Android Volley JSON requests load as data receives

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, android-volley

Hey guys we're doing our network GET and POST requests via Volley, every thing is pretty good. but there is one problem: Our JSON results from server varies from 3 to 5 MB and that's really heavy to load, also we can't cache those results for later use. Is there any way to load data in list as data receives from server just like requests done by browser? I think there was something called Deferred/Promise or something like that in JScript. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wel, in an Android app, your data can exist in memory, or in a file. I would recommend downloading your data directly to a file, then using a reader to read it part by part. Take a look at this answer to make volley download data directly into a file without an in-memory byte-array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26523191/volley-download-directly-to-file-no-in-memory-byte-array

Comment: you need to clarify your question. Do you want to "stream load" the data? from the volley docs : "Volley is not suitable for large download or streaming operations, since Volley holds all responses in memory during parsing."

Comment: Nope i don't want stream load, I just want to user be able see some of loaded results while rest of data is loading by the time it receives.

Comment: That's stream loading.  Volley doesn't do that.